# deleting a list from another json list in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

This is the main json list

```
allData=
{
    "searchList": [{
        "vaccinationId": 1,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 1",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }, {
        "vaccinationId": 2,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 2",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }, {
        "vaccinationId": 3,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 3",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }, {
        "vaccinationId": 4,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 4",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }, {
        "vaccinationId": 5,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 5",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }, {
        "vaccinationId": 6,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 6",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }]
}
```

This is the existing json list

```
alreadyExist = {
    "searchList": [{
        "vaccinationId": 2,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 2",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null,
        "defaultYn": null
    }, {
        "vaccinationId": 5,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 5",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null,
        "defaultYn": null
    }]
}
```

Had to remove the existing data from the main json list, so the result will be

```
allData = {
    "result": [{
        "vaccinationId": 1,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 1",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }, {
        "vaccinationId": 3,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 3",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }, {
        "vaccinationId": 4,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 4",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }, {
        "vaccinationId": 6,
        "vaccinationName": "vacc 6",
        "vaccinationNameAr": null
    }]
}
```

How can  achieve to get the new all data list by removing the existing data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `forEach` and `map`

```
 alreadyExist.searchList.forEach(function(existInfo) {
       var index = allData.searchList.map(function(e) { return e.vaccinationId;    }).indexOf(existInfo.vaccinationId);

    if(index != -1) {
        allData.searchList.splice(index, 1);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#differenceBy) for this purpose

```
allData.searchList = _.differenceBy(allData.searchList, alreadyExist.searchList, 'vaccinationId');
```

Comment: This is method that Lodash Offers. You find this on given link on Lodash. It is a utility library that offer many useful utility methods with great performance